# Cryptic Error when using firebase in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase-authentication, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying out `Firebase` authentication using Google sign in, in my rails application.

When the user clicks the Signin button a sign in popup with google taught to appear.

However i keep getting this cryptic error message saying

```
TypeError: this.ta is not a function[Learn More] firebase.js:1:100034
Ii   https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase.js:1:100034
r    https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase.js:1:196629
<anonymous>   http://localhost:3000/:39:27
```

autheticate.erb.html

```
<h1>Authentication Test</h1>
<button id="sign">Signin</button>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  var config = {
    apiKey: "api_key",
    authDomain: "mydomain",
    databaseURL: "database_url",
    projectId: "myproject",
    storageBucket: "bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "message_id"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config)

  let elem = document.getElementById("sign");
  elem.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let google_provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(google_provider).then(function(result){
      console.log("succesful.... Google account linked")
      console.log(result)
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log("Failed...... ")
    })
  })
```

I am using

`Firebase v 5.5.3`

`rails v 5.6.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because of the following line:

```
 let google_provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
```

`new` should be used:

```
 let google_provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
```

Comment: You're a life saver, thanks a million. Please were can i get a complete updated documentation to work with.

Comment: @wokorodouyesamuel here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/